# Xcode 4.2 on Mac OS X version 10.7.4

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I have Mac OS X version 10.7.4 installed and I want to have the Xcode 4.2 installed on my machine.
But when I try to install the 4.2 dmg it gives the error as

Xcode is not supported on Mac OS X 10.7 or greater.
To install Xcode you must download a version that supports Mac OS X 10.7 or greater.

Actually I don't want to change the Base SDK of my existing app to point to 6.0 and kep it as 5.0 only.

What should I do?

Comment: What's the issue with changing the Base SDK?

Comment: I can't change the base sdk to older value as i don't have it installed.

Comment: You said in your question that you didn't want to change the Base SDK from 5 to 6.  Why not?

Comment: It will take lots of efforts for me to support latest sdk for my app as it has lot many calls deprecated with new sdk. To minimise th ebuidl eforts i want to stick to my current sdk version an dnot the latest one. Moreover I am not using any feature which is specific to the newer SDK so I can be OK without support for that SDK.

Comment: Just because you link against the latest SDK doesn't mean you support all the features of that SDK.  Your app will be the same until you actually code it to use the new features.  Just ensure the deployment target is set correctly and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely are trying to install the Snow Leopard version of Xcode 4.2. There's a version of Xcode 4.2 for Lion on Apple's developer downloads site that should work. If you want to avoid using the iOS 6 SDK, you could install Xcode 4.3 or 4.4 instead of 4.2. Both Xcode 4.3 and 4.4 have the iOS 5 SDK and run on Lion.